# Set error message of Kentico BizForm with method registered to BizFormItemEvent

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I have registered a method to `BizFormItemEvent.Insert.Before` that checks if a user already exists with an email address provided in the form and creates a user if it doesn`t.

If the user *does* exist with that email address, then I want to display an error message.  Problem is, if you try to call `e.Cancel()` or throw an exception, the BizForm just displays the generic `"An error occurred when saving data. Please see event log for more details"` message, and I`m not sure how I can alter that message.

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
using CMS.Base;
using CMS.OnlineForms;
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Partial class that allows you to register custom handler methods and classes.
/// Adds the CustomFormHandlers attribute to the partial class.
/// </summary>
[CustomFormHandlers]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom attribute class.
    /// </summary>
    private class CustomFormHandlers : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called automatically when the application starts
        /// </summary>
        public override void Init()
        {
            BizFormItemEvents.Insert.Before += FormItem_InsertBeforeHandler;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the form data when users create new records for forms
        /// </summary>
        private void FormItem_InsertBeforeHandler(object sender, BizFormItemEventArgs e)
        {
            BizFormItem formDataItem = e.Item;

            if (formDataItem != null && formDataItem.BizFormClassName == "bizform.formname")
            { 
                // CreateUser returns false if a duplicate email is found
                if(!CreateUser(formDataItem))
                {
                    // Something needs to happen here that
                    // changes the error message of the bizform
                    // e.Cancel();
                    throw new Exception("A user with this email address already exists.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find out a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a **Custom form control** and implemented the validation in the **IsValid** method. Example [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Example+-+Developing+custom+form+controls).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do that in BizFormItemEvent.Insert.Before event. Try to implement custom validation rule for that field:

- it will prevent form from being saved
- it will allow you to specify validation error message